# Alfresco 3.3 - Selecting document based on category

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

We have limitation of using 3.3 for sometime. Simple scanerio:

1. Created a folder structure in Site.
2. Created couple of documents in a folder under site
3. Created categories
4. Applied couple of categories on documents

Now I need to fetch those documents based on categories....

Tried:
1. CMIS way. - Not possible.
2. What other way?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a Lucene search, like this:

```
PATH:"/cm:categoryRoot/cm:generalclassifiable/cm:Languages/cm:German//member"
```

You can run that search from the node browser to try it out. You can also run it from server-side JavaScript, like this:

```
var results = search.luceneSearch('PATH:"/cm:categoryRoot/cm:generalclassifiable/cm:Languages/cm:German//member"');
print (results.length);
```

Comment: I am sorry as I am new to Alfresco. I want to know if i have to write a java program to do Luence search, can you point me to some sample code or something keeping in alfresco 3.3 in mind. Also what JAR would i have to include.

Comment: Go to the Node Browser in Alfresco Share and run the PATH Lucene search. If you want to run the server-side JavaScript you can create a JS file in Data Dictionary/Scripts then run the "Execute Script" action against a document or folder. Or, install Florian Maul's JavaScript console and run it from there. Or, write a Java class, inject the SearchService, and then use it to run the search.